# C# ASP.NET checkboxlist on page load check items from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, checkboxlist, selecteditem

I am working with checkboxlist in asp.net and what I WANT TO do is next: for selected user get his roles from database ( lets say roles are previously selected and stored to database and that is ok!) and now I just want to fill that checkboxlist with selected roles (in previous step)  from database..

But unfortunately I can not do that on the way I imagined it might work, here is my code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    int playerID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["player"]);
    var player = DAPlayers.GetByIgracId(playerID);

    if (player != null)
    {
        checkboxRoles.DataSource=DAPlayers.GetAllRoles();
        checkboxRoles.DataTextField = "Name";


        player.Roles =DAPlayers.GetAllRolesByPlayer(player.playerID);

        for (int i = 0; i < checkboxRoles.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if(player.Roles.Contains(checkboxRoles.Items[i])) //HERE I GOT THE ERROR 
                checkboxRoles.Items[i].Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR NUMBER 1:

> cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to
>   'MYPROJECT.Data.Roles'

ERROR NUMBER 2:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(MYPROJECT.Data.Roles)'
>   has some invalid arguments

My Role class

`public partial class Roles
    {
        public Roles()
        {
            this.UserRoles = new HashSet();
        }

```
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
}`
```

Thanks guys,

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `Text` property like `checkboxRoles.Items[i].Text` and again while comparing you will have to compare it with a `string` property of `Role` object which can't say for sure unless you post the code for `Roles` class

Per your comment: In that case get the `Names` list and compare with that like

```
var roleNames = igrac.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);

 if(roleNames.Contains(checkboxRoles.Items[i].Text)) 
   checkboxRoles.Items[i].Selected = true;
```

Comment: yes it looks like it works I will test it little bit more now! So can you explain to me little bit this line of a code: `var roleNames = igrac.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);`

Comment: It means gets names of my roles, and after that check if that names exist in allroles, if so make them checked?

Comment: @billy_56, that's a one liner LINQ query to get the Name property from the List<Role> and thus you have List of role names with which you can compare chkbox text

Comment: @billy_56, yes exactly ... inorder to facilitate the comparison with chkboxroles text since you can't compare text/string with your custom Role object. Hope this helps.